# Unknown storage engine 'InnoDB' Server type: MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have four MySQL database, out of four two database showing "#1286 unknown storage engine 'innodb'" in phpMyAdmin when I try and view a table:

my.cnf value

```
[mysqld]
default-storage-engine=MyISAM
performance-schema=0
max_allowed_packet=268435456
```

[my.cnf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KY75I.png)

and

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW ENGINES;
+--------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| Engine             | Support | Comment                                                                                          | Transactions | XA   | Savepoints |
+--------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| MRG_MyISAM         | YES     | Collection of identical MyISAM tables                                                            | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| CSV                | YES     | CSV storage engine                                                                               | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| Aria               | YES     | Crash-safe tables with MyISAM heritage                                                           | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| MyISAM             | DEFAULT | MyISAM storage engine                                                                            | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| MEMORY             | YES     | Hash based, stored in memory, useful for temporary tables                                        | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| InnoDB             | NO      | Percona-XtraDB, Supports transactions, row-level locking, foreign keys and encryption for tables | NULL         | NULL | NULL       |
| SEQUENCE           | YES     | Generated tables filled with sequential values                                                   | YES          | NO   | YES        |
| PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA | YES     | Performance Schema                                                                               | NO           | NO   | NO         |
+--------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Stopped MySQL and delete /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile0 and 
/var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile1 then start MySQL again but not working.

PS. I Manage my server. Please don't flag or report, as I need to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post your full `my.cnf` ?

Comment: ie my full my.cnf

Comment: Add to your question the full content of your `my.cnf` file!

Comment: i added a screenshot of my.cnf. Please check

Comment: Look at `mysqld.err` or wherever the error log is.